# If the bot creates a text channel, how could you select the channel that it has just made and have the bot post a message in it?

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a server and want a bot. It has a ticket system. You do ,ticket (reason), then it will create a private text channel with the user and some support, however when the text channel is made I would like the bot to say first:
@Support , @(user that called the ticket) has made a ticket for (reason)

Current code:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ticket(ctx,*,reason):
    global ticketNumber
    ticketNumber = str(ticketNumber)
    global supportRole
    supportRole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Support")
    overwrites = {
        ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        ctx.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
        supportRole: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }
    name = 'Tickets'
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name=name)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    await guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ticketNumber}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
    ticketNumber = int(ticketNumber) + 1
    await ctx.author.send("Your ticket has been made, a support team member will try to answer it ASAP. Thank you.")
    await ctx.send(reason)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(id=ID NUMBER))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately `create_text_channel()` returns the created channel 
and to get a mention of a role, u can use `role.mention`.

---

```pyhton
ticket_channel = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel(f'Ticket-{ticketNumber}', category=category, overwrites=overwrites)

msg = f'{supportRole.mention}, {ctx.author.mention} has made a ticket for {reason}'
await ticket_channel.send(msg)
```